# flutter [Only static members can be accessed in initializers]

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a true beginner in flutter and dart.
I have a problem concerning playing youtube videos using [ youtube_player_flutter: ^6.1.1]
I create a Json file with youtube links and I want to link it with [ youtube_player_flutter: ^6.1.1]. but it always displays the error message [Only static members can be accessed in initializers]

```
          @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // this function is called before the build so that
        // the string assettoload is avialable to the DefaultAssetBuilder
        setasset();
        // and now we return the FutureBuilder to load and decode JSON
        return FutureBuilder(
          future:
              DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: true),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            List mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
            if (mydata == null) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Loading",
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return quizpage(mydata: mydata);
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }

    class quizpage extends StatefulWidget {
      final dynamic mydata;
      ////////var youtubeUrl;
      quizpage({Key key, @required this.mydata}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _quizpageState createState() => _quizpageState(mydata);
    }

    class _quizpageState extends State<quizpage> {
      var mydata;

      _quizpageState(this.mydata);

      int marks = 0;
      int i = 1;

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }
  YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(mydata[4]["1"]));
    super.initState();
  }

  void nextquestion() {
    setState(() {
      if (i < 10) {
        i++;
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => resultpage(marks: marks),
        ));
      }
```

The problem is that I want to make the  [String videoURL ] plays the list of videos in my json data file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you declared variable ```mydata``` twice. The first instance is in the state object and the second instance is in the stateful widget @Montasser Mohamed

Comment: Hello, I do not see any error here, is there any other code we can look at?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I updated the code so that if you can give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Possibility is that you coded the variable `mydata` twice. This is the format you should follow. And in order to make use of the variable from the StatefulWidget from the constructor, use `widget.mydata`. Don't have to declare it twice.

**Code:**

```
class Quizpage extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic mydata;

  quizpage({Key key, @required this.mydata}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuizpageState createState() => _QuizpageState();
}

class _QuizpageState extends State<Quizpage> {
  /* 
    You can make use of your mydata in this class like this:
    widget.mydata, and you will be able to make it work
  */
  Color colortoshow = Colors.indigoAccent;
  Color right = Colors.green;
  Color wrong = Colors.red;
  int marks = 0;
  int i = 1;

  // String videoURL ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OAdfB2U88A&t=593s";
  YoutubePlayerController _controller;


  // Use like this to make use of your array mydata
  String videoURL = widget.myData[4]["1"];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(videoURL));
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Also, this is for coding point of view. Please follow the correct way of naming classes in Flutter. Always use **CamelCase** or **Have your first letter of the class as capital**. This is the best practice while you write your code. I hope the above helps you in some sense. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concert, But I'm still confused as I don't know where I should put [mydata[4][i.toString()];]. when I insert it in videoURL it generates an error. Also when I insert it in initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId());      It is not works either.  What should I do

Comment: Hey @MontasserMohamed, I have edited the code. Check I have made changes in the **videoURL** data. See, if that works for you

Comment: Thanks. I followed your steps but It still throws the same error. I also added more details to the code in my question if you can help me.

Comment: Do you get the same error as **[Only static members can be accessed in initializers]** after using the my updated code or different one? If different one, that means your question has been answered, and if you want something else then you should make changes to the question

Comment: Yes, sir. I still get the same error now under the Widget and when I remove it, the error returns to videoURL